# Kiwi-tcms | junit-plugin | Not able to publish test results to Kiwi

Tags: java, junit5, kiwi-tcms

I have selenium automation test framework written in JAVA. Integrated with Junit5 and kiwi's junit-plugin.

Im trying to update test execution on kiwi based on my automated test result. First, im wondering is that doable?

Im able to create connection and login, but there are no familiar methods to update test execution for specific test case.

```
    RpcClient kiwi = new RpcClient();
    kiwi.login("my_username", "my_password");
    //I need here something like 
    kiwi.updateTestCaseExecution("specific_test_run", "specific_test_case", "test_status");
    kiwi.logout();
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have selenium automation test framework written in JAVA. Integrated
> with Junit5 and kiwi's junit-plugin.
>
> Im trying to update test execution on kiwi based on my automated test
> result. First, im wondering is that doable?

As you have already seen it is.

> Im able to create connection and login, but there are no familiar
> methods to update test execution for specific test case.

See this method: https://github.com/kiwitcms/junit-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/kiwitcms/java/api/RpcClient.java#L243 First parameter is the TE ID, the second one is a status ID.

> I cannot get this ExecutionId based on CaseID

You need TestExecution.filter() to filter by runId and caseId:
https://github.com/kiwitcms/junit-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/kiwitcms/java/api/RpcClient.java#L228

Also see https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms.rpc.api.html#module-tcms.rpc.api for information what parameters are accepted by the API and how to make queries.

Please be a good open source citizen and consider contributing your Selenium glue code at https://github.com/kiwitcms/api-scripts to help others who may be interested.

Update:

> TestCase[] testCases = kiwi.getRunIdTestCases(2);

The raw JSON returned by  the underlying TestRun.get_cases() API method contains both `status` and `execution_id` fields but the Java serializer code in the junit-plugin library ignores them b/c they aren't part of the TestCase model, see `model/TestCase.java`.

Comment: Hello @Alexander Todorov, I am struggling to integrate my selenium test with JUnit. It there any complete guideline or tutorial with full insturaction

Answer (score 0):

I'm very close now:

there are method for updating Test Execution:

```
kiwi.updateTestExecution(ExecutionId,status);
```

but I cannot get this *ExecutionId* based on CaseID

[image]

if i run:

```
TestCase[] testCases = kiwi.getRunIdTestCases(2);
```

I get:

[image]

there are no Execution ID

Comment: Have you sucess?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431647/alexander-todorov

full example:

```
        //create client instance
        RpcClient kiwi = new RpcClient();

        //login
        kiwi.login("username", "password");

        //every selenium test case should have assigned case id (from kiwi)
        int runId = "your_run_id";

        //search for execution ID based on case ID and run ID
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("run_id", runId);
        params.put("case_id", "your_case_id");
        TestExecution tcExec = kiwi.getTestExecution(params);
        int tcExecId = tcExec.getTcRunId();

        //update execution with results
        kiwi.updateTestExecution(tcExecId, 5);

        //test statuses
        //1 - IDLE
        //2 - RUNNING
        //3 - PAUSED
        //4 - PASSED
        //5 - FAILED
        //6 - BLOCKED
        //7 - ERROR
        //8 - WAIVED
```

Comment: Can you help me to do it in my code?

Comment: I am confued in /.tcms.conf and environment.. Where I need to update it